# How to generate Design File(html) from a page layout created in Design Manager(aspx only)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have no experience on sharepoint, but I have to update a page content, I created a page layout using the sharepoint designer, however it does not create html file. the reason I created one is because I need to update the layout with additional control and ofc I cant do that with the existing layout. I tried the following scenario, downloaded the aspx and uploaded it to the master gallery, I also tried creating one from the page layout on the design manager, that generate both files however I still need to include some new stuff into the page.

Sorry I am so lost, I've been googling for 2 days now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant automatically generate the html page layout from an ASPX version. The conversion only works from HTML to ASPX.

So you need to create the page layout as html first either manually or through Design manager (which you have done successfully).

Once created you can modify the HTML version to add snippets from the snippet gallery or your custom HTML. When you check it in and publish, it will update  the ASPX version automatically.

If you inspect a HTML version with ASPX version. you will notice that there are more or less the same but when there is ASPX tags used they are wrapped in various comment tags such as SPM,MS etc. You could manually convert the aspx version into a html version by removing these comment tags.

The following guide should explain it further,

http://sharedpointtips.blogspot.com/2015/05/sharepoint-2013-create-custom-page.html

Comment: Yeah I figured that what I'm doing is opposite, is in sharepoint terms is snippet = controls (.net terms)? how can I add additional control(richtextfield) to the html using snippet to modify the existing page layout?

Comment: thanks for your answer I got it!. i just created an updated page layout and copy the snippets it created on the html code with the new control then copied that to the original page layout html.

Comment: glad you got it sorted. Please mark as answer if you feel its appropriate